# Error Code: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax when importing Data into a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-8.0

I am importing a database exported from a MySQL 5.6 server into a 8.0.22 server. Everything works well until I hit these statements:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AddNewUsers`;

DELIMITER $$

/*!50003 SET @TEMP_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' */ $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddNewUsers`(emailx text, telx text,pwdx text, rolex text, namex text, classifctnx text, facultyx text,
 departx text, classabbrx text)
BEGIN
insert into users(email, tel, pwd, role, name, regdate,classifctn, faculty, depart, classabbr) values
(emailx, telx, password(pwdx), rolex, namex, sysdate(),classifctnx, facultyx, departx, classabbrx);
insert into staff(email, tell,departmnt, faculty,regstatus,staffname, staffcate) values (emailx,telx,departx,facultyx,'Pending',namex,
classifctnx);
END $$
/*!50003 SET SESSION SQL_MODE=@TEMP_SQL_MODE */  $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The error received is below:

```
Error occured at:2021-04-07 13:37:03
Line no.:2059
Error Code: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(pwdx), rolex, namex, sysdate(),classifctnx, facultyx, departx, classabbrx);
ins' at line 5
```

I am assuming the problem has to do with the `password` statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This function is deprecated in MySQL 5.7 and is removed in MySQL 8.0.= https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password

Comment: Thanks! I will setup a MySQL 5.6 server for this. Thanks.